# Send POST data in email body - Django

Tags: python, django, email

I would like to send my post data in the body of an email.

I would like to do something like this, but the body dict is obviously not the right format (this returns the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`). What is the best practice for accomplishing this?

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def send_mail(request):
    body = {
         'name': request.POST['name'], 
         'phone': request.POST['phone'],
         'email': request.POST['email'],
         'appointment prefs': request.POST['appt'],
         'message': request.POST['message'], 
     }
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Website Inquiry', 
        body, 
        to=['myemail@gmail.com']
        )
    email.send()
```

Here's the error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/send_mail

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['apps.cphh',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'smartfields']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:
File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/Documents/pet_health_harmony/pet_health_harmony/apps/cphh/views.py" in send_mail
  31.     email.send()

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  342.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  111.                 sent = self._send(message)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in _send
  125.         message = email_message.message()

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in message
  301.         msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in __init__
  214.         MIMEText.__init__(self, _text, _subtype=_subtype, _charset=_charset)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py" in __init__
  30.         self.set_payload(_text, _charset)

File "/Users/kristaprokopczyk/.virtualenvs/megan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in set_payload
  224.                 for l in payload.splitlines()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /send_mail
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

Comment: where do you call `splitlines`? Please share your code thoroughly so we can help.

Comment: I don't use Django, but can you dump that dict into a json and try?

Comment: Please show your real code. This wouldn't even compile; you have `[]` wrapping your `body` dict instead of `{}`.

Comment: Sorry, this is my code. I had changed the {} to [] to try something else and abandoned that idea.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever This is my full code; I don't call splitlines explicitly.  It happens in `email.send()`. I updated my post with the full traceback.   Note if i pass a string as the `body` argument the function works properly.

Answer (score 3):

The issue stems from `EmailMessage` wanting a single string for the message content and it's being given a dict.

That needs to become a string, this should do it.

```
# turn the dict into a set of strings
content = {"%s: %s" % (key, value) for (key, value) in body.items()}
# turn those strings into 1 block of text separated by newlines
content = "\n".join(content)
email = EmailMessage(
    'Website Inquiry', 
    content, 
    to=['myemail@gmail.com']
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. For some reason I thought there would be a different solution than simply converting it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use json.parse to convert it to string and then send this string in the body of the mail.

```
import json

def send_mail(request):
    body = (........)
    body = json.parse(body)
    ...........
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try `request.POST.get('name')` instead.